# Python to fill out web forum

Tags: python, forum, fill

I am trying to use python to login to this page(which i own!) http://ninitelist.yolasite.com/passprotected.php
and return true if a password is correct and false if the password is wrong. I am at a total loss of how to do this, oh and please dont suggest mechanize, i cant figure out how to install it. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) to POST form data.

import urllib

```
def try_login(username, password):
    params = urllib.urlencode(
            {'username': username,
             'password': password })
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://ninitelist.yolasite.com/passprotected.php", params)
    return "Invalid login details" not in f.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print try_login("testuser", "testdata")
```

Comment: You're welcome! I edited my example to refactor the code so that it more closely matches what you asked for.

Comment: Yeah, im actually gonna use it to test a dictionary attack (against my site) which is why i needed a return value